# htaccess 301 redirect adding ‘?’ and unwanted segments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I’m using something like this:

```
Redirect 301 /old http://example.com/new
```

which redirects to http://example.com/new?old

I don’t want the first variable adding to the second so how can I avoid this?

Could it be becasue of the RewriteCond/RewriteRule elsewhere in the document? The full doc looks something like this:

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Remove index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

# Remove www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Section redirects
Redirect 301 /old http://example.com/new
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the [mod_rewrite-docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

> Modifying the Query String
>   By default, the query string is passed through unchanged. You can, however, create URLs in the substitution string containing a query string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution string to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine new and old query strings, use the [QSA] flag.

which means that you can add a '?' at the end of your redirect target to remove the "old" query_string.

Try this:

```
# Section redirects
Redirect 301 /old http://example.com/new?
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, it still adds the question mark to the redirect though. I ended up using a RewriteRule once I figured out it had to be above the part where I was removing index.php

Answer (score 1):

As @Seybsen points out, a question mark can be used to remove the query string.

I found I could also use a `RewriteRule` as long as it was positioned correctly in the document. It had to be above the the part where index.php was being removed.

```
RewriteRule ^old http://example.com/new [R=301,NC,L]
```

Alternatively, to use the query_string:

```
RewriteRule ^old(.*) http://example.com/new$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```